# Sort an array of strings based on an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to do the following operation: sort an array of strings based on an array of numbers of equal length. For example:

```
A=[a,b,c,d,e]
B=[1,3,2,5,4]

A'=[a,c,b,e,d] //<=The desired outcome
```

Basically, I am thinking about sorting the array A based on sorting array B into ascending order. Here, I am thinking about implicit value pairs, just like objects.

I can think of creating an object, sorting it, and then separating out the array of strings, but this is probably too much code and am wondering if there is a simpler method to achieve this.

Any advice will be welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: _"...creating an object, sorting it,..."_ - You cannot "sort" an object.

Comment: Try this `A.map((x,y)=>{return {"string":x,"number":B[y]}}).sort((x,y)=>x.number-y.number).map(x=>x.string)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to sort anything here.
Just use the numbers as "positions" from where to get the value for the current index/position in the result.

```js
const input = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
const order = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];

const result = order.map(position => input[position - 1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome reply really I was not thinking about this

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of code golf:

```js
const A=['a','b','c','d','e'];
const B=[1,3,2,5,4];

// for this to work, we have to assume A and B have the same length
// if you implement this into a function, do such a check yourself first

const sorted = A.map((item, index, arr) => arr[B[index] - 1]);
console.log(sorted);
```

This will work as long as B is AT LEAST as long as A, and if B is filled with numbers

Answer (score 0):

You might use a for loop and add the value from A getting the index from B.

```js
let A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
let B = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];
let C = [];

for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) C[B[i] - 1] = A[i];

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom order, then you can create an object with order:

```js
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let b = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4];

let order = {a: 1, b: 3, c:2, d: 5, e:4};

const result =  a.sort((a, b) => order[a] - order[b]);
console.log(result);
```